# How can I integrate a rotating camera view in my anylogic model?

Tags: anylogic

I have been trying to incorporate a camera that rotate 360 degree around my model automatically.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a camera as below. When navigating to it, ensure to enable the `follow` flag like this:

`my3Dwindow.setCamera(cam_Floating, true, 500l);`

[image]
NOTE:

- the `sin` and `cos` notations!
- the X & Y initial values (“680”) mark the center point of the rotation
- the divisor (“7000” below) is the duration for 1 circle, in ms
- the multitpliers (“1000” for X aboveand “600” for Y) stretch the circle radii (so above we have not a circle but an oval along the X axis)